# Block element background as opposed to child inline element background

Tags: html, css

Why do the descenders of the anonymous inline text inside the [p](/questions/tagged/p) element stick out of the background or (content-area) of the [p](/questions/tagged/p) element, while the [span](/questions/tagged/span) element's background (or content-area) contains the descenders (and potential ascenders) of the text? Is this related to em-box calculations of the font, a block element not fully containing inline children, or maybe line-height 1 equal to font-size being an issue? https://jsfiddle.net/norkuy/462wzvq1/

```css
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  background: tomato;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p span {
  background: DarkSlateGray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>A sentence containing <span>ggg's</span> and <span>jjj's</span></p>
```

Comment: The line-height property doesn't inherit into inline elements. So the span overflows out of the p just like the descenders of the p do. (Change the span to inline-block and see the same happen to the letters in the span.) Not sure what else there is to say. You were looking for a solution? The only solution is to not make the line-height too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` elements, which are `block` elements, have their height calculated from the `line-height` of `1`, which is calculated from the `font-size` of `40px`. So the `p` has a calculated `height` of `40px`, which isn't enough to cover the descenders.

The `span` elements, which are `inline` elements, have their height set automatically based on their content. They'll even ignore any height properties assigned to them. So the height, and `background-color` covers the required space.

As an additional example, I've copied the same snippet but applied a class to turn the `span` elements into `inline-block` elements, which will obey the height we've defined.

```css
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  background: tomato;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p span {
  background: DarkSlateGray;
  color: white;
  
  /*
  /  No matter what we do
  /  we can't change the height
  */
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 40px !important;
}

.turnedIntoBlock {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>A sentence containing <span>ggg's</span> and <span>jjj's</span></p>

<p>A sentence containing <span class="turnedIntoBlock">ggg's</span> and <span class="turnedIntoBlock">jjj's</span></p>
```

Comment: and to prove this, i would add an example where I set span to inline-block and we obtain the same height as p ;)